# Search data using Nativescript

Tags: search, nativescript

I get correctly all data from this function:

```
getallpharma() {
    this.pharma.mobile_base_pharmacyGetAll().subscribe(
        items => {
            this.items = items;
        },
        err => console.error('err', err),
        () => console.log('error')
    );
}
```

This is JSON

```
{ "StatusCode": 0,
"StatusMessage": "OK",
"StatusDescription": [
    {
        "pharmacy_id": "011E752345553380ABC13FFA163ECD15",
        "name": "Pharmacy",
        "email": "email@testpharmacy.com",
        "website": "testpharmacy.com",
        "address1": "Test Pharmacy, Test Country, Test City",

    },
    {
        "pharmacy_id": "011E762345552280FBC13FFA163ECD10",
        "name": "Test Pharmacy",
        "email": "email@testpharmacy.com",
        "website": "testpharmacy.com",
        "address1": "Test Pharmacy, Test Country, Test City",

    }
]
```

}

For search I am using this function that doesn't work:

```
public items: Array<FarmaciaData> = [];
 public myData: ObservableArray<FarmaciaData> = new ObservableArray<FarmaciaData>();

    public onSearchSubmit(args) {
        let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
        let searchValue = searchBar.text.toLowerCase();
        this.myData = new ObservableArray<FarmaciaData>();
        if (searchValue !== "") {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                if (this.items[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) !== -1) {
                    this.myData.push(this.items[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you share with me any idea how to search data in this function?

Comment: I guess you are using Angular, you don't really have to depend on ObservableArray in that case. If your UI is not updated then may be it's something the way you do it, might be the issue with change detection. Please share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Demo https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HlFUkD

Comment: @Manoj have you any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's purely logical,

```
    let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
    let searchValue = searchBar.text.toLowerCase();
    this.filteredCountries = searchValue.length ? this.countries.filter(item => {
        return item['name'].toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
    }) : this.countries;
```

when you don't have search text return everything, when you do convert name to lower case and filter.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HlFUkD&v=4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function of array. I have updated your Playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HlFUkD&v=2).

in your .ts

```
let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
        let searchValue = searchBar.text.toLowerCase();
        if (searchValue) {
            this.filteredCountries = this.countries.filter(item => {
                return item['name'].includes(searchValue)
            })
        } else {

        }
```

P.S. In my project, I have created a pipe to retunr the filtered data.